# Dissect square into triangles of same perimeter

Tags: geometry, triangles

Given the unit square, it is clearly possible to dissect it into any even number of triangles of the same perimeter (the triangles being even isometric). But I wasn't able to find such a dissection for 3 triangles (or 5...). Is it possible?

Comment: For 3 triangles, there are simply too few patterns possible. One of the triangles must have a full side of the square as part of its perimeter, which already severely restricts our options.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen : thank you for your comment. Would you have an idea for $5$ triangles (or an odd number)?

Answer (score 3):

UPDATE: A rectangle 1 by 0.964394 (or $4 - 22x + 67x^2 - 112x^3 + 64x^4=0$) can be divided into seven triangles with equal perimeter.

[image: Seven equiperimeter triangles]

I did some looking for 5, with various base triangles, and then ellipses on the unpaired edges to assure equal perimeters.  Nothing obvious popped out.  Here's the closest I got, with seven equal perimeter triangles almost completing the square. Point H has an $x$ value of $(10 - 3 \sqrt5)/10$.

[image: seven triangles]

In [Wheel Graphs with Integer Edges](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/WheelGraphsWithIntegerEdges/), I give examples where integer-sided triangles can complete a wheel graph.  So far, all solutions have areas with 1 or 2 area radicals.  [Triangle Radicals](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/TriangleRadicals/) has lists of triangles of a particular radical.

The following Heronian triangles all have the same perimeter.  So they might be able to complete a wheel graph, or even complete an [integral drawing](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IntegralDrawing.html).  But likely not.

{{25, 25, 48}, {13, 40, 45}, {17, 40, 41}, {24, 37, 37}, {25, 34, 
  39}, {29, 29, 40}}

But there are many larger sets of equiperimeter triangles with the same radical. Someone could plow through them to see if there is a set to fill out a square.

Comment: Thank you for your interesting contribution!

Answer (score 2):

There is a famous [theorem by Monsky](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monsky%27s_theorem) saying that you cannot partition a square into an odd number of triangles of equal *area*. The proof is not easy, and some authors even take recurse to the axiom of choice for a proof. Anyway: To obtain a theorem about an odd number of triangles of equal *perimeter* should be even more difficult since square roots are entering the picture.

Comment: Thank you. I am aware of Monsky's theorem (which can be proved in ZF — no need of the axiom of choice). Why would the case of perimeter be more difficult?

Comment: Monsky's theorem also rules out the dissection of a rectangle into seven triangles of equal area. A dissection of a rectangle into seven triangles of equal perimeter has been demonstrated. Therefore, Monsky's theorem doesn't apply here.